# Cannot install sendmail or update Ubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 17.04, sendmail

I am trying to install sendmail, however whenever I run `sudo apt-get install sendmail`, I end up with the following error messages:

```
Err:1 http://mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 procmail amd64 3.22-25ubuntu0.17.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 procmail amd64 3.22-25ubuntu0.17.04.1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/procmail/procmail_3.22-25ubuntu0.17.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Running sudo apt-get update, or trying again with --fix-missing has no effect, the following still shows up as Not Found. Checking on this issue, I found out that the problem could be that Zesty's End Of Life was back in January.

The problem here however, is that attempting to install the update from the settings, or with dist-upgrade fails. Dist-upgrade specifically returns a significant amount of 404 errors. As for updating from settings, this is the error returned:

```
Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

apt transaction returned result exit-failed
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe this manual will hep you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I decide to write an answer , because I've read for the same problem several times last days, for example this one: [Can't install Apache2 on Ubuntu 17.04 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.25-3ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018065/cant-install-apache2-on-ubuntu-17-04-depends-apache2-bin-2-4-25-3ubuntu2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are currently using EOL (end-of-life) distribution of Ubuntu. You can check this on the page: [Ubuntu release end of life](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life). This is the reason why its repositories are `404  Not Found`. You simply can try to open any `Failed to fetch` package in your browser and will see the same - it doesn't exist.

[image]

The way to recover from this situation is to follow the manual [**EOL Upgrades**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) on Ubuntu Doc.